# Calculating the mass of elementary particles

Tags: particle-physics

How exactly are the masses of fermion particles calculated using Higgs field interactions and Yukawa couplings

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. The elementary particle masses are measured, and axiomatic in the table of elementary particles in the standard model, not calculated.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model . The higgs mechanism explains how from zero mass , they end up with mass, but it is a mechanism, not a calculation that will give mass. The masses have to be measured and are an input to the model.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the mass $m$ and the Yukawa coupling $\lambda$ of a fundamental fermion is simply $$m = \frac{v}{\sqrt2}\lambda,$$ where $v$ is the vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field. The Yukawa couplings are free parameters in the Standard Model. They are found by measuring the masses, so there's no real calculation going on here.

Comment: i.e. measured masses

Comment: Just to be difficult ... Do radiative corrections rescale these induced masses uniformly, or do they distort ratios?